# Cakephp 4.x Admin Authentication repeated Controllers needed?

Tags: cakephp-4.x

If I have a UsersController and want to have an admin Prefix, do I need to have one controlle for all basic user functions, and another UsersController inside /Admin with only admin functions? Am I supposed to have two UsersControllers in my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CakePHP's [**prefix functionality**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing), then yes, you'll have two `UsersController` classes, that's how it's supposed to be. It's not a problem as prefixes do map to namespaces, so the controllers will live in different namespaces, one in `App\Controller` and one in `App\Controller\Admin`.

If you bake the controllers they'll automatically land in the right place:

```
bin/cake bake controller Users
```

```
bin/cake bake controller Users --prefix Admin
```

To share common functionality between both controllers, look into using [**components**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components.html).

Comment: I didn't know that second bake option for prefix. That's great. Thanks!